# Turning on hotspot automatically turns off my Wi-fi in my Moto g4 plus

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g

With android kitkat (in my Moto g1), i could share my wi-fi via mobile hotspot. After upgrading to lollipop, turning on hotspot would turn off the Wi-fi which i thought was a bug.
Now to my surprise, it is happening in my new Moto G4 plus (marshmallow). If this is a feature, then i do not understand why it behaves like that. Is there a way i can share my wi-fi via mobile hotspot ? Sharing the 3G data does not make any sense to me.

Comment: See settings > wireless networks> more> tethering and mobile Hotspot> set up WiFi Hotspot.  Don't you find that option?

Comment: @beeshyams That's not the issue. Ishan can turn on the hotspot – but that turns off the "normal WiFi". Intention is obviously to have the device acting as a router (WiFi in – WiFi out).

Comment: You could still achieve the goal (i.e sharing wi-fi) with help of some third-party applications. It uses wi-fi direct to share the wi-fi connection making the device pretty much like a wi-fi repeater. See here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173875/what-is-the-functionality-concept-behind-wi-fi-sharing-aka-wi-fi-profile-share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device has to support 2 WiFi frequencies, *and* the OS has to implement the feature (e.g. Huawei D2 and Samsung S7/Edge), or else you will only get either WiFi in or WiFi out. I've never seen any mention of the original G supporting the feature either, and since I've owned an original G myself, I can say that it can't do it in my experience.

The only way that was able to do it on non-OS-level was FQRouter2, but it's now obsolete and might not work.

Comment: I researched around and realized that i am an ignorant idiot who thought that he is sharing Wi-fi with hotspot while possibly 3G data is what was being shared. I never used hotspot that much so as to notice any substantial 3G data loss.