# How does Wi-Fi sharing in Samsung Galaxy S7 work?

Tags: wi-fi

Starting from Galaxy S7, Samsung added a new cool feature called Wi-Fi sharing, by which you can connect to an Access Point and turn on your hotspot at the same time. That means, you can now turn on your Wi-Fi and hotspot at the same time, something that was not possible in any other phones till date. So, how do they do it? Is it something possible to do in code, or you have to have a special hardware?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I happened to ask a similar question which wasn't well received (months ago), but what I did eventually was to dig up, researching and fortunately **found a solution**. I was trying to mimic this feature on a non-samsung device, in case you wish to see my findings see here:  [What is the functionality concept behind Wi-Fi sharing (aka Wi-Fi Profile share)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/173875/209414)

Answer (score 2):

## Software, not hardware

Thanks to the brilliant research of xavier_fakerat

If you look here, [What is the functionality concept behind Wi-Fi sharing (aka Wi-Fi Profile share)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173875/what-is-the-functionality-concept-behind-wi-fi-sharing-aka-wi-fi-profile-share)

You will see that software can accomplish this. So it's not just a special hardware thing.

You can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en To get similar results that the S7 produces