# How does Samsung's WiFi Sharing work on a low level?

Tags: samsung, wifi-tethering

Samsung have had a feature called WiFi Sharing in their Android devices for some time.

This extends the tethering or hotspot function to be able to share another access point via its own SSID (with the same configuration that'd normally be used for sharing LTE).

How does this work on a low level? Could this function theoretically be added to other Android devices or even AOSP? What features of a WiFi chipset allow this to work?

I see [What is the functionality concept behind Wi-Fi sharing (aka Wi-Fi Profile share)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173875/what-is-the-functionality-concept-behind-wi-fi-sharing-aka-wi-fi-profile-share) but it only talks about the Android side, not the kernel or hardware side. It's also pretty incorrect as WiFi Sharing (at least on the S8+) doesn't use WiFi Direct at all.

Comment: Those phones have 2 sets of WiFi hardware AFAIK, and that alone would prevent the feature from being available elsewhere.

Comment: @Adam post you linked in your question  doesn't explain how wi-fi sharing for Samsung works, hence the question it explains another workaround of how the same concept was used on non Samsung phones, to give the same result, **so it is pretty much correct** an also uses **Wi-fi direct over VPN**, read the post again you will understand, even the illustrations doesn't include a Samsung device FYI I don't even use a Samsung device, so there is no way I can go claim incorrect stuff

Comment: Also I am suspecting you didn't read the **remarks** on the bottom of that  post, please do if you care.